# Insert a ♥ into MySQL (heart character) via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a heck of a time getting ♥ type characters into my database using  php.

I've got UTF-8 setting on the page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and

```
<?php
$line = $_REQUEST['line'];
$line = stripslashes($line);
$line = htmlspecialchars($line);
$line = trim($line);
$line = mysql_real_escape_string($line);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (txt) values ('$line')";
mysql_query($sql, $cn);

?>
```

the result of the insert is a **?** character

i'm sure there are people who've done this, but I'm really having trouble getting it right.

edit:

the MySQL table's collation and field's encoding is also set to utf8_unicode_ci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to do: `SET NAMES utf8` as your first query.

Comment: hmm it shouldn't be a reason. SET CHARACTER SET do the same as SET NAMES. And it's still before query execution. @Alex does it really slove your problem?

Comment: yeah it sure did!  (i'd have voted for the green checkmark sooner but stack has a delay on accepting answers :)

Maybe it's something to do with the version / settings / etc... on the server.